# DateTime.Compare Validation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I keep getting this error for my DateTime Validation code at DateTime.ParseExact and have no idea what the problem is

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

The string startDate and EndDate is being entered from a textfield which needs to be verified and the startDate cannot be greater than the endDate. It is supposed to throw an error if the user presses the submit button if the date is not entered in correctly.

```
 String startDate = Request["txtStartDate"];
    String endDate = Request["txtEndDate"];
    DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (DateTime.Compare(start, end) > 0)
    {
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        Msg = " The end date must be a later date than the start date. ";
        lblError.Text += Msg;
        validatedState = false;

    }
    else
    {
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

    }
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what an example startDate and endDate string looks like?  I tested your code with  String startDate = "10/03/2010"; String endDate = "08/22/2010"; and it works fine.  I think the startDate and endDate strings you're receiving are in a format that can't be converted to DateTime which is causing the error.  If you can update your question with an example of the string output I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Before setting `start` you might do something like `string inputDates = string.Format("Dates are '{0}' and '{1}'", startDate, endDate);` and output `inputDates` so you can see *exactly* what is being passed. Note the primes around the strings so you can see if there are unexpected spaces etc.

Comment: updated question with the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DateTime.TryParseExact`to first test if the datetime strings passed are valid. Then you can provide an error message if it does not pass validation.

```
        String startDate = Request["txtStartDate"];
        String endDate = Request["txtEndDate"];

        DateTime start;
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out start))
        {
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            Msg = " The start date is a invalid format.";
            lblError.Text += Msg;
            validatedState = false;
            return;
        }

        DateTime end;
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(endDate , "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out end))
        {
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            Msg = " The end date is a invalid format.";
            lblError.Text += Msg;
            validatedState = false;
            return;
        }
        if (DateTime.Compare(start, end) > 0)
        {
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            Msg = " The end date must be a later date than the start date. ";
            lblError.Text += Msg;
            validatedState = false;

        }
        else
        {
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        }
```